# What are the pronouns for man as humankind?

Tags: pronouns

I was reading a book and this came up:

> Man has programmed machines to transcend their limitations.

and I got confused that whether the author is referring to man or machines? Can we use **their** as a pronoun for man as humankind?
So can anyone say what are the pronouns for man as humankind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Their" is the plural possessive.  "Man" is singular and masculine, meaning the possessive pronoun should be *his*.

> Man has programmed machines to transcend **his** limitations.

So "their" must refer to machines.  But suppose the writer instead used *men*, or the gender-neutral *people*, or something similar:

> **Humans** have programmed machines to transcend their limitations.

In this case, "their" is completely ambiguous.  You'd have to figure out which it refers to from the context, or just take your best guess.